# How to parse a binary data collection (list of files) from multipart/form-data http response?

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, multipartform-data

How to parse a multipart/form-data of **http response from server**, if it contains a list of binary files (images)?

For example:

```
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('GET', url);
  var streamedResponse = await request.send();

    if (streamedResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse); // it is just a binary data, not a list of files
    }
```

Maybe there is something similar to HttpMultipartParser from .NET in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

***Try below solution***

```
Future uploadmultipleimage(List images) async {
  var uri = Uri.parse("");
  http.MultipartRequest request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
  request.headers[''] = '';
  request.fields['user_id'] = '10';
  request.fields['post_details'] = 'dfsfdsfsd';
  //multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile("imagefile", stream, length, filename: basename(imageFile.path));
  List<MultipartFile> newList = new List<MultipartFile>();
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    File imageFile = File(images[i].toString());
    var stream =
        new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
    var length = await imageFile.length();
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile("imagefile", stream, length,
        filename: basename(imageFile.path));
    newList.add(multipartFile);
  }
  request.files.addAll(newList);
  var response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Image Uploaded");
  } else {
    print("Upload Failed");
  }
  response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was about how to parse the multipart response from server with list of files.